# Find a number $m$ such that $P[X \leq m] = P[X \geq m] $

Tags: probability, self-study

A continuous random variable $x$ has a pdf of the form $f(x) = 2x/9$ for $0 < x < 3$ and $0$ otherwise. I've tried integrating $xf(x)$ between $0$ and $\infty$ looking for $E(X)$ but that gives me a polynomial which will just blow up when I take the limit. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $m$ is the median.

Comment: @dsaxton thank you, problem solved $$\int_{0}^{m} 2x/9 dx = 1/2$$

Comment: Why would you integrate $xf(x)$? That doesn't give probability.

Comment: @Glen_b this is my first class in probability and I thought the question was asking for $E(X)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since OP has solved it, let's make sure this doesn't end up unanswered.

Since $f$ is continuous, the presence or absence of equality doesn't change the probability.

So if $P(X\leq m)=P(X\geq m)$ then $P(X\leq m)=\frac12$.

So you just find $m$ such that $P(X\leq m)=\frac12$. This is a simple definite integral (as the OP suggests in comments, we simply solve for $m$ in the equation $\int_0^m f(x) dx=\frac12$ -- this is simple in this case).